# How to sort photos by camera device model - bash

Tags: bash

There is a need to find Photos taken on Lumia 720 some period ago and copy them to a specific folder using Exif.

```
for f in $(find /Volumes/exFatPro/ -mtime +1095 -maxdepth 10 -type f -iname "*WP_*" | grep "Lumia 720"); do
  cp -v "$f"  /Volumes/exFatPro/2013test
done
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you try? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. As an addition to the above comment by @Marian I suggest you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to give you a better chance of getting an answer to your question.

Comment: for f in $(find /Volumes/exFatPro/ -mtime +1095 -maxdepth 20 -type f -iname "*WP_*" | xargs -0 exiftool -a | grep "Lumia 720"); do cp -v "$f"  /Volumes/exFatPro/2013test; done

Comment: cp: /Volumes/exFatPro//backups/cell/Nokia: No such file or directory
cp: Lumia: No such file or directory

I'm getting to much errors that say 'No such file or directory'. I assume that spaces and special characters are not letting me to copy the files

Comment: I'm using ExifTool so that to sort photos by Exif data